# Can't set up LAN server with Terraria 1.2.4

Tags: terraria

I want to play two-player with my bro now that 1.2.4's out, but it's just not working. He types in the IP with the default 7777 port, but it just gets eternally stuck on the connection. Is this a bug? Or is there something else I need to do? When I was in 1.2.3 I could play via Hamachi with my friends, but I can't get it to work via plain ol' LAN.

Comment: so you don't want to have external computers connecting to your server?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have set everything up correctly? If your friend can't connect, then it might be because you did something wrong, or forgot to do something when setting up the server. And I wouldn't recommend using Hamachi, if that's what you are using. I would recommend setting up port forwarding and creating a server using the regular Terraria server software, or the newly released Gameiki server software, but for Gameiki you would have to download something called the *Gameiki Mod Installer*, and install the mod to your local Terraria installation, and then on the same page download the server software and then extract it to anywhere on your computer.

I would personally recommend using the regular server software though as it's easier for beginners. And if you don't know how to set up port forwarding, let me know and I'll help you out as I know how to port forward.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was trying to set up a simple LAN game for just two people, not a full-time, port-forwarded server. I'm not using Hamachi this time, just regular LAN. I've used Gameiki before. It's questionable at best; it sticks around on your computer after Terraria updates, and is very difficult to get rid of. I wouldn't be surprised if it's a trojan.

Comment: Did you successfully get the regular LAN to work?

Comment: No. It's probably a bug with 1.2.4.